# PHP attempting to compare two dates, to display fee

Tags: php, date

I am working on editing some code for a client and have had some tough time figuring this one out. I attempting to compare two dates and based on the difference set a fee to a certain amount, but I am having issues comparing the dates. The first date is picked by the customer and the second date is set to todays date, the fee is supposed to be 25 if the customer arrival date is the same as today or within 1 day; for example today is 01/25 if the arrival date is 01/25 or 01/26 the fee should be 25, if the arrival date 2 days or more from todays date the fee is 0.

The date the customer picks is in the format : m/d/Y
selected by:

```
<tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;"><td style="text-align:right;">Arrival Date:</td><td><input id="arrivaldate" name="arrivaldate" value="<?php if (strlen($arrivaldate)>4) { echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($arrivaldate)); } else { echo date("m/d/Y"); } ?>" placeholder="click here for arrival date" readonly></td></tr>
```

I have tired various ways to convert and calculate this and have googled but its not populating properly, here are my attempts at calculating the fee:

```
  $date1 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
$date2 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d",$arrivaldate_converted));
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);


$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d");
$expressFeeDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 days', $arrivaldate_converted));
$todaysDateConverted = new DateTime($todaysDate);
$expressFeeDateConverted = new DateTime($expressFeeDate);   
$expressInterval = $todaysDateConverted->diff($arrivaldate_converted);

if ($expressInterval->days <= 1)  {

   $expressfee= 25.00;

// echo '<br>include express fee';

}else if($expressInterval->days>=2 || $expressInterval->days>1){
    $expressfee= 0;

} else {
 // echo '<br>do not include express fee';
  $expressfee=0; 


}
```

Thank you for any feedback, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this ?

```
$date1 = new DateTime($today);
$date2 = new DateTime($choosen_date);

// Should have the days difference between your 2 dates
$diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%a");
```

Then should be easy to set your fee...